# X configuration not being applied to device?

Tags: xorg, input

I've got [a configuration file](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19/blob/master/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-synaptics-bcm5974.conf) which I'm installing at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-synaptics-bcm5974.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "MacBook Pro Touchpad"
  MatchUSBID      "05ac:0272"
  MatchUSBID      "05ac:0273"
  MatchUSBID      "05ac:0274"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Driver          "synaptics"

  # lookup options here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/synaptics

  # detect your palm over the trackpad and disable while typing
  Option "PalmDetect" "1"

  # require actual clicks, no tapping!
  Option "TapButton1" "0"
  Option "TapButton2" "0"

  # disable edge scrolling
  Option "VertEdgeScroll"  "0"
  Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "0"

  # don't do corner taps for things
  Option "RTCornerButton"  "0"
  Option "RBCornerButton"  "0"

  # raise the minimum and maximum tracking speeds
  Option "MinSpeed" "1.2"
  Option "MaxSpeed" "1.85"
EndSection
```

The kernel driver providing this device is `bcm5974` and I want it to use the synaptics driver, which it does. Here are the other files in that configuration directory:

```
10-evdev.conf
10-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
50-synaptics.conf
50-vmmouse.conf
50-wacom.conf
51-synaptics-quirks.conf
52-synaptics-bcm5974.conf
```

The `50-synaptics.conf` is a sort of "catchall" configuration file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

I'm assuming that since my configuration file has a higher priority, it'll be the one used for the specific device I'm attempting to configure it for.

However, my device doesn't get automatically configured properly and seems to be getting caught by the catchall driver. When I look at the output of `synclient` and observe functionality, it's not respecting my configuration. (For example `RTCornerButton` should disable the right corner click, and it doesn't)

Is there something I'm missing here? Is there a way to debug which configuration is being applied to my device?